# How to track blocking that happen for less than a second - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I am trying to troubleshoot a blocking issue which happens for less than a second. 
The OLTP application is very sensitive and has to have an response time of less than 200ms for some transactions as per the agreed SLA. 
We had some lock escalation issues with the new code release which we were able to solve with reducing the batch size in the updates.
Even with the small batch size, we suspect that the new sp is blocking the same rows that the OLTP transactions is updating.

I need to find the session that is getting blocked and the resource its waiting on. As per my understanding "blocked process threshold" can set for a minimum of 1 second and so this will not capture the blocking.

I am experimenting with wait_info and wait_completed x events.

Is there any other way we could track this. Thanks

Comment: same question on so by same user :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407021/best-way-to-track-locks-sql-server/38407626#38407626

Answer (score 10):

As you are specifically interested in locking rather than general waits the `locks_lock_waits` extended event sounds more suitable.

With a filter on `increment >= 200`

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [locks_lock_waits] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.locks_lock_waits(
        ACTION(sqlserver.sql_text)
            WHERE  ( [sqlserver].[is_system] = 0
                     AND [increment] >= 200
                     AND [counter] <= 1000 ) 
    )
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer;

GO

ALTER EVENT SESSION [locks_lock_waits]  
ON SERVER  STATE = start;
```

The above gathers the statements waiting on locks for the threshold amount of time but doesn't give the specific lock resource.

I have never used this event and have no insight into how much overhead this session would cause on your production server.

I found [this video](http://blog.sqlworkshops.com/extended-event-locks-lock-waits-in-sql-server/) on the topic. That does strongly recommend filtering on `counter` to reduce the number of events collected and I have done so above.

It also mentions an old legacy undocumented command

```
dbcc lock(StallReportThreshold, 200) -- 200 is threshold in ms
```

Which (if trace flag 3605 is enabled) dumps out limited information such as the below to the SQL Server error log.

> Process 53 waited 6844 ms for S lock on RID: 2:1:120:2 result: OKWAIT

I just mention this in passing as extended events would be clearly preferable anyway as it is documented and much more powerful.

Comment: I tested locks_lock_waits, and like you said it does not have the resource info.  But i didnt know that increment was time.  Good info
dbcc lock, looks great.  Do you know how long that information is available before it is can be dumped to error log.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt make my self clear.  I was asking , how long we have until we run the dbcc lock command.  Eg locking happens and if i run dbcc lock after an hour, do we still get the info?

Comment: @jesijesi - I'd never heard of it before today. I don't have any more information on it. I don't even know the parameters to pass to disable it. But you run `dbcc lock(StallReportThreshold, 200) ` first and it outputs the info once the threshold is exceeded as long as trace flag 3605 is enabled. SQL Server doesn't collect this info just in case you might run it later.

Comment: Thanks.
just adding a link that has a useful function to convert the resource_0,1,2 values in xevents.
http://www.sqlnotes.info/2011/10/24/locking-and-blocking-5-lock-resources-in-extended-events/

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in locking, there are several extended events available:

```
lock_acquired
lock_released
lock_escalation
```

The first two events have a `duration` column in (microseconds) which you could filter on for your thresholds.  They also have a `resource_description` action which will give you some detail on the resources involved.

The `lock_escalation` event also has a `statement` action which you can add to collect the T-SQL statement that triggered the lock escalation.  It also has `escalation_cause`.  Here's a sample session:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [locking] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_acquired( SET collect_resource_description = (1) ),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_escalation( SET collect_statement = (1) ),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_released( SET collect_resource_description = (1) )
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

I suspect there is probably a reason you can't set the blocked process report threshold to less than a second: locking is perfectly normal in an RDBMS - the database engine has to lock resources in order to protect them.  Although there is not an official definition as to when locking becomes blocking, locking ticking over sub-second, seems kind of normal to me.

Comment: locking becomes blocking as soon as someone else is denied access to the resource and has to wait due to the lock.

Comment: Thank, I am planning to use lock_acquired with the duration field.

Comment: Good luck.  As you are on SQL Server 2014, you could use In-memory OLTP tables with natively compiled stored procs offer a high performance latch-free option.  You could also look at snapshot isolation.